# How do I rename a file with Fog?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fog

I have a rails 3.2 app. Using fog to store files in S3.

I would like to write a script to rename all of the files that have been uploaded. I can't seem to find any fog documentation in this area.

Is this possible with fog? Do I need another gem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bad news is you need to do a get/create/destroy

```
foo = bucket.files.get 'foo'
bar = bucket.files.create :key => 'bar', :body => foo.body
foo.destroy
```

The good news is if you're doing it from ec2 in the same region it will probably happen as fast as renaming a file on your local computer

Answer (score 13):

What about copying as mentioned in [this post](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1336)?
cf. [fog's requests sources](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/copy_object.rb) and [fog's models sources](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb).

You should be able to do:

```
storage.copy_object('old_bucket', 'old_filename', 'new_bucket', 'new_filename')
```

or

```
file.copy('new_bucket', 'new_filename')
```

Destroying the original file after a successful copy remains necessary though.

Comment: The parameters are out of order in the storage.copy_object example above. Should be old_bucket, old_filename, new_bucket, new_filename according to the source at https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/copy_object.rb

Comment: @MelindaWeathers, taken into account in the answer.

Comment: In this case fog will take advantage of S3's `copy` command and you don't have to transfer the file contents to your local system. Much faster.